# Could not able to add abstact class instance to list

Tags: c#, wcf, abstract

I am having the follwing Objects ValidationType, ValidationRule, ValidationProperty, ValidatorBase( abstract class), NotNullValidatorRule (derived from ValidatorBase abstract class)as follows.

```
public class ValidationType
{
    public ValidationType();

    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string DefaultRuleSet { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ProcessId { get; set; }
    public List<ValidationRule> RuleSet { get; set; }
    public long SubProcessId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationRule
{
    public ValidationRule();

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ValidationProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public long TypeId { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationProperty
{
    public ValidationProperty();

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long RulesetId { get; set; }
    public List<ValidatorBase> Validators { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ValidatorBase
{
    protected ValidatorBase();

    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Negated { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string TemplateResourceName { get; set; }
    public string TemplateResourceType { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public abstract XNode GetValidator();
}

public class NotNullValidatorRule : ValidatorBase
{

    public override XNode GetValidator()
    {
        try
        {
            XElement validation = new XElement("validator",
                    new XAttribute("type", this.Type),
                    new XAttribute("name", this.Name),
                    new XAttribute("messageTemplateResourceName", this.TemplateResourceName),
                    new XAttribute("messageTemplateResourceType", this.TemplateResourceType),
                    new XAttribute("messageTemplate", this.MessageTemplate),
                    new XAttribute("negated", this.Negated),
                    new XAttribute("tag", this.Tag));
            return (XNode)validation;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }       
}


I have WCF Service to return a List<ValidationType>,

  public List<ValidationType> GetValidationRules(long processId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ValidationType> ResultValidionTypesList = new List<ValidationType>();

            List<ValidationType> ValidationTypes = new List<ValidationType>();

            ValidatorBase CodeMandatory = new NotNullValidatorRule();
            CodeMandatory.Name = "CodeMandatory";
            CodeMandatory.TemplateResourceName = "";
            CodeMandatory.TemplateResourceType = "";
            CodeMandatory.Type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.NotNullValidator,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
            CodeMandatory.Tag = "display:none";
            CodeMandatory.Negated = true;
            CodeMandatory.MessageTemplate = "";
            CodeMandatory.GetValidator();
            ValidationProperty CodeProperty = new ValidationProperty();
            CodeProperty.Name = "Notes";
            CodeProperty.Validators.Add(CodeMandatory);


            ValidationRule CompanyTypeRules = new ValidationRule();
            CompanyTypeRules.Name = "CustomerGroupRuleset";
            CompanyTypeRules.Properties.Add(CodeProperty);

            ValidationType CompanyValidationsTypes = new ValidationType();
            CompanyValidationsTypes.Name = "iBoxV5.Model.CMS.Masters.CustomerGroup";
            CompanyValidationsTypes.DefaultRuleSet = "CustomerGroupRuleset";
            CompanyValidationsTypes.AssemblyName = "iBoxV5.Model.CMS.Masters, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
            CompanyValidationsTypes.RuleSet.Add(CompanyTypeRules);

            ResultValidionTypesList.Add(CompanyValidationsTypes);

            return ResultValidionTypesList;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RollBackTransaction();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }

    }
```

And the above is returning the List of values if I did not add the

//CodeProperty.Validators.Add(CodeMandatory);

statement. And If I trying to add the Instance of a NotNullValidatorRule( which is derived from ValidatorBase(Abstract class)) then the below WCF service error occurs. However the same validationTypes is returning List including the NotNullValidaitonRule in console application.

'Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.'

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Could anyone pls clarify about what went wrong..!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

WCF infrastructure must be aware about all of `ValidatorBase` descendants being serialized/deserialized to perform these actions. You should provide this info for your data contracts via [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
public class ValidationType {}

[DataContract]
public class ValidationRule {}

[DataContract]
public class ValidationProperty {}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(NotNullValidatorRule))]
public abstract class ValidatorBase {}

[DataContract]
public class NotNullValidatorRule : ValidatorBase {}
```

Comment: Sorry! Dear.. its says ." interfaces cannot declare types". Could you please clearify..